# How to update some global variables used in 'scroll' event when 'resize' event is fired in JQuery / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some variables globally declared:

```
var a = $('.ela');
var b = $('.elb');
var top_a = $('.ela').offset().top;
var top_b = $('.elb').offset().top;
```

I use these variables on "scroll" event applied to the `<main>` element:

```
$('main').on('scroll', function(top_a, top_b) {
// do something with top_a and top_b
}
```

Now, I need to use the updated values of these variables at the event  $(window).resize(), so I write:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   top_a = $('.ela').offset().top;
   top_b = $('.elb').offset().top;
})
```

This way the global variables are updated, but in $('main').on('scroll', function etc) I get the old values...

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the variables to `scroll` event at

```
$('main').on('scroll', function(top_a, top_b) {
// do something with top_a and top_b
})
```

`top_a` would reference the `event` object, not `top_a` variable.

You can pass the variables using `event.data`

```
$('main').on('scroll', {top_a:top_a, top_b:top_b}, function(event) {
   // do something with top_a and top_b
   console.log(event.data.top_a, event.data.top_b)
});
```

or, directly by referencing the variables

```
$('main').on('scroll', function(event) {
   // do something with top_a and top_b
   console.log(top_a, top_b)
});
```

Comment: Thanks @guest271314, after your answer I made small searches on topic and now I understand better how passing parameters to an event handler works! I wonder only if in this case a closure can be a solution, like:

`$('main').on('scroll', myFunction(top_a, top_b) {
     // do something with top_a and top_b
})`

and:

`function myFunction(top_a, top_b) {
   
   return function() {

    // do something with top_a and top_b

    
}

}`